# how to enable UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled in .NET6?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

In .NET Framework,Have you enabled client side validation in the web.config:

```
<appSettings>
 ...
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Or enabled it through the HTML Helper:

```
HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
```

how to enable UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled  in .NET6?
Is there a need to do this?

Comment: it is enable as default. did you check validation scripts?

Comment: @OkanKaradag When I use the ajaxlink in .NET6 MVC Razor,I get Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined error. It is because of the disable UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled.Other cases have been observed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core MVC/Razor Pages, it contains `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` file by default in `wwwroor/lib` folder, but you need add reference to the view to enable them.

If you just want **enable them in specific view**, you can use these scripts and just add the partial view inside the `.cshtml` file like this:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

If you want to **enable them in every view**, you can add it in `_Layout.cshtml` like below:

```
    //.....
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    //add this reference here.....
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

If you also want to use `Ajax.ActionLink` in ASP.NET Core, this way is only apply to ASP.NET MVC 5.2. In ASP.NET 6, you need use an alternative way.

For example:

In ASP.NET MVC 5.2, you use

```
@{
    AjaxOptions deleteOptions = new AjaxOptions()
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "table"
    };
}
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = 1 }, deleteOptions)
```

In ASP.NET 6, you can use

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#table" data-ajax-url="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = 1})">Delete</a>
```

Also remember to add the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` reference in your view:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" integrity="sha256-v2nySZafnswY87um3ymbg7p9f766IQspC5oqaqZVX2c=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

}
```